# Evaluate $\int_{S^1} \frac{z}{\cos(z)}\, dz $

Tags: complex-analysis

Am I right?
I need to evaluate:
$$\int_{S^1} \frac{z}{\cos(z)} \, dz $$

I use the Cauchy formula and write:

$$ 2i\pi g(0) = \int_{S^1} \frac{g(z)}{z} \, dz$$ where $$g(z) = \frac{z^2}{\cos(z)}$$

Then $g(0) = 0$ and the integral evaluate to zero too.

I also have some doubt about using the cauchy formula, because $\cos(z) = 0$ for $|z| = \frac{\pi}{2}, |z| = -\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Thanx for the help.

Comment: Use Cauchy's theorem, not CIF. Also, last line of OP contains an error.

Comment: @JJacquelin No, $S^1$ is the unit circle, *of course*.

Comment: OP: Can you explain your "doubts" much more clearly?

Comment: The zeros of $\cos z=0$ are reals.

Comment: You have $\cos z = 0$ for $z = k \frac{\pi}{2},$ where $k \in \mathbb Z,$ but none of these is inside the unit circle, so there the integrand is holomorphic and the integral is $0$.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the help. I mistakenly didn't realize that $\frac{\pi}{2}$ was not on the unit circle. What OP does mean?